# Dialog Error react native - children doesn't exist on type intrinsicattributes and dialogprops

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've tried using this sample code for an alert dialog in my react native app, but it gives me an error on Dialog (where I've put the ***) saying

> TS2322: Type '{ children: Element[]; visible: boolean; onDismiss: ()
> => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogProps'.   Property 'children' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & DialogProps'.

And when I run the app then press the open alert dialog button I get the error in the app saying Render Error: usePortalContext must be used within a Portal Context and I'm not sure what this means. The code I used for my dialog was just straight copied and pasted from  the docs here https://www.react-native-material.com/docs/components/dialog so I'm not sure why it's not working

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {
      Button,
      Dialog,
      DialogHeader,
      DialogContent,
      DialogActions,
      Text,
    } from '@react-native-material/core';
    
    const Dialog_ = () => {
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    
      return (
        <>
          <Button
            title="Open Alert Dialog"
            style={{margin: 16}}
            onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
          />
          <Dialog*** visible={visible} onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)}> 
            <DialogHeader title="Dialog Header" />
            <DialogContent>
              <Text>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum
                eligendi inventore, laboriosam laudantium minima minus nesciunt
                pariatur sequi.
              </Text>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button
                title="Cancel"
                compact
                variant="text"
                onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
              />
              <Button
                title="Ok"
                compact
                variant="text"
                onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
              />
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Dialog_;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got the same error and looking carefully at the example, I saw that the App was wrapped with Provider component:

```
const AppProvider = () => (
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

I added the Provider component in my function and in the import part and then the Dialog displayed correctly.

Comment: Ah I missed that, thanks!